# ID of a Box Item from the Embedded Link?

Tags: box-api

I am working in C# and trying to find the file id or shared link (which I can use to get the id) of a file in box so the user can pull information about the file or download it, but the only reference to the file I have is the embed link.

How can I find either the id of the file or the shared link from an embedded box link like https://www.box.com/embed/06giwf1i41bu6jo.swf?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what you are trying to accomplish?  How are you getting the embed link?  Are you scanning some website with a bit of embedded content that is being served from Box?  I think with a little more explanation of what you are trying to accomplish, we can help you more

Comment: Yes i am crawling my company's website for box content. It is surfaced as embedded links but to download them to the new content system i need the download link. I would go straight from Box.net but I need the items in the context of the website.